# How to find the average velocity of blood?

Tags: calculus, integration, physics, average

The velocity $v$ of blood that flows in a blood vessel with radius $R$ and length $L$ at a distance $r$ from the central axis is
$$v(r) = \frac{P}{4\eta L}(R^2 − r^2)$$
where $P$ is the pressure difference between the ends of the vessel and $\eta$ is the viscosity of the blood (See Example.). Find the average velocity (with respect to $r$) over the interval $0 \leq r \leq R$.

$v_{\text{ave}} =$______

Compare the average velocity $v_{\text{ave}}$ with the maximum velocity $v_{\text{max}}$.

$\dfrac{v_{\text{ave}}}{v_{\text{max}}}=$_____

This problem is driving me crazy, I understand average value and have no problem with solving average value problems.  However I do not know what the question is asking of me, I have tried many different answers on web assign with no luck.

I am given a link to an explanation of blood velocity with an example in it giving me numbers $R=.008~\text{cm}$, $L= 2~\text{cm}$, $\eta =.027$ and $P =4000~\frac{\text{dynes}}{\text{cm}^3}$ and an example radius of $r =.002~\text{cm}$.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You just need to find the average value of a function, so you integrate and divide by the length of the interval.

Comment: so, this is a web assign homework problem from stewarts calculus book?

Comment: Yes it is, I have tried solving the integral both with the numbers and without with no luck, I could have made a mistake but I have tried both multiple times.

Comment: @Alek Well, as a start, you say $v(r) = P4\eta L\left(R_2 - r_2\right) \leftarrow$ there is no $r$ in the right hand side of this--so is $v(r)$ _supposed_ to be a constant?  It's also kind of strange to write $P4$ instead of $4P$--i.e. $v(r) = 4P\eta L\left(R_2 - r_2\right)$

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  I was only able to figure out what you meant because I found the problem in Stewart's book.

Comment: @Alek All you need to do is find $\frac{\int_0^R v(r)dr}{R - 0}$ (which should not be a difficult integral to find).